# Unexpected Token when importing react-native-fetch-blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs

We are trying to import the react-native-fetch-blob package package using the following code:

```
const RNFetchBlob = require('react-native-fetch-blob');
const firebase = require('firebase');
```

However, when we try and build, we get a Syntax Error for Unexpected token import as follows.

> C:\Users\ ...\node_modules\react-native-fetch-blob\index.js:5
>      import {
>      ^^^^^^
>      SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>      at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
>      at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
>      at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
>      at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
>      at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
>      at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
>      at Object.
>     (C:\Users\ ...\build\cloud\file.js:159:243)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)

We are using ES6 and our .babelrc file looks as follows

```
"plugins": [
    ["transform-runtime", {
        "polyfill": false,
        "regenerator": true
    }]
],
"presets": ["react-native","es2015",]
```

Is there a solution to this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: have you found a solution to your problem? I am facing a similar issue with my tests throwing this error.

Comment: Wondering the same as @DavidNathan Any luck?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to work around this problem by creating a mock for react-native-fetch-blob (rn-fetch-blob, in my case).  The mock suggested here worked for me: https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob/issues/212#issuecomment-340706825

> As @scerelli I also wanted the mock to happen in a separate place so it can be used by all tests. Placing the following code in /**mocks**/react-native-fetch-blob.js seems to work for me:
>
> const existsMock = jest.fn();
>   existsMock.mockReturnValueOnce({then: jest.fn()});

```
export default {
DocumentDir: () => {},
ImageCache: {
    get: {
        clear: () => {},
    },
},
fs: {
    exists: existsMock,
    dirs: {
        MainBundleDir: () => {},
        CacheDir: () => {},
        DocumentDir: () => {},
    },
    },
};
```

> It's a variation of @SoundBlaster solution, just in a global mock file. With that I don't need to import or implicitly mock anything in the test code.

Comment: I had to make the folder root/__mocks__/rn-fetch-blob.js